# Can't uninstall a package - Component is in use - can'd locate the 'using' object

Tags: managed-package, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall a package:

I get an error I can't uninstall, as one field is in use by another object
[image]

I am unable to locate the using component: Sales_analytics_1 . (the name indicates view in my opinion).

Is there a way I can search my org's views to see if that name exists?

It's not a report - I searched.

Thank you

Comment: You can try the free [Metadata Search](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI) app if you're unable to find the component by looking through Setup.

Answer (score 2):

In [Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205614&type=1) says that if the component is not linked in the description of the problem It used to be a workflow. So search the workflows for that Sales_Analytics.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, FlowDefinition table has no 'Sales_Analytics'. I also did not see any Process builder or flows with this api name

Comment: Workflow Rules are not stored in the `FlowDefinition` table. The linked article has suggestions for reviewing them.